# Android App - remove extra padding

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble removing the extra padding set by default. I'm not really familiar with Java that much but I've set the **margin** and the **padding** to **0dp** of the **Linear Layout (Vertical)** and the buttons are still not covering the whole page.

> To be more clear, I want the buttons to cover the entire front page. None of the gray area to be visible.

**Visual:**

[image]

**Styles.xml**

```
resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.it5.foothillers.MainActivity"
    android:background="#f4f4f4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:text="NEWS"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="48dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SPORTS"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="48dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:text="EVENTS"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="48dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:text="MORE"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:background="#f1f108"
            android:textSize="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you didn't see that part `android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"` in the top level layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove these lines from activity_main.xml

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: Hey, you're a hero! THANK YOU @Dmitri

Answer (score 1):

You can find @dimen/activity_vertical_margin and set value as 0dp also..
That way if in future you want to add back again then you can use these..

file location res/values/dimen.xml

Comment: You just taught me something new! Thanks @Shyam

Answer (score 1):

You still have the padding from your `RelativeLayout`:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Get rid of these and you should be okay.

Comment: Hey thanks but the first response worked for me already. But thank you!