# Android App - the toolbar goes away when I debug the app

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio, the app shows like I expect it to. Although when the app is debugged, the banner that displays the name of the app disappears.

Where did I make an error?

**To be more clear, here's how it shows on Android Studio:**

[image]

**Here's how it shows when I run the app (as you can see there's no banner)**

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.it5.foothillers.MainActivity"
    android:background="#f4f4f4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:text="NEWS"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="0.28"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="48dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SPORTS"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="48dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:text="EVENTS"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="48dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:text="MORE"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:background="#f1f108"
            android:textSize="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

if your app extends `Activity` please change if to `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: If you look at an [older post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36269706/2308683) by this user, it would appear that theme is already used.

Comment: thank you ,i guess he only needs the `AppCompatActivity`..

Comment: Hey, you're a hero!!! Thank you!! It worked :)) @MounirElfassi

Comment: you are welcome, glad to help,you can upvote now you have 20 points hhh

Comment: I up-voted!!! Thank you that was such an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your class extends AppCompatActivity and if still you don't see the action bar, try changing the theme of your app in the AndroidManifest.xml to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

You can also try setting this in your styles.xml in res

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

I hope it helps! Kind regards!

Comment: The actionbar is displayed by changing class extends to AppCompatActivity. It worked!!! such an easy fix @Isaac